# HTTParty + JSON-LD Content-Type response

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, json-ld, httparty

How do we deal with HTTP requests that accepts only 'application/ld+json'? I have simple GET request that accepts only application/ld+json Content-Type. Example code:

**app.rb**: (Sinatra server that accepts requests from a client, acts as a middleware)

```
helpers do
  def institutions(payload)
    ApiRequest.new(payload).institutions
  end
end

get '/' do
  payload = {}
  payload['fullSearch'] = params['fullSearch']
  payload['token'] = request.env['HTTP_X_ID_TOKEN']
  institutions(payload).body
end
```

**api.rb**

```
class ApiRequest
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://api.dev.example.com'

  def initialize(params)
    @token = params['token']
    @options = {
      query: { fullSearch: params['fullSearch'] },
      headers: headers
    }
  end

  def headers
    { Authorization: "Bearer #{@token}", Accept: 'application/ld+json' }
  end

  def institutions
    self.class.get('/institutions', @options)
  end
end
```

So I am aware of adding a before method to get the respective content type

```
before do
    content_type :json
end
```

How do I do the same for ld+json content types? Are there any difference between JSON and JSON-LD in the scope of Ruby? Or do I just assume the content to be JSON and parse normally?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the sinatra-linkeddata gem, which will return JSON-LD, although by serializers an RDF graph. Otherwise, just register a `:jsonld`minne type.

Most JSON-LD processors will happily process plain JSON, but there are some subtle differences.